# Atributo de classe com valores pré determinados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, annotation

Quero criar um atributo da classe para o sexo (**M** ou **F**), que por padrão a pessoa já possa selecionar. É possível criar um array com estes valores (**M** e **F**) já padrão sem que seja preciso digitar, ou deverei fazer isso no layout mesmo?

```
[DisplayName("SEXO")]
[StringLength(1, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Selecione o Sexo")]
public string Sexo { get; set; }
```

Do jeito que está aqui (acima) seria um campo para a pessoa digitar, pensei em fazer tipo um:

```
public list<Sexo>...
```

**ALTERAÇÃO**

```
namespace Projeto.Models
{
    public enum Sexo { M = 1, F = 2 }

    public class Pessoa
    {
        [Key]
        public int PessoaID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Nome")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter de 3 a 255 caracteres")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        ...

        [DisplayName("SEXO")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Selecione o sexo")]
        [StringLength(1, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Selecione o Sexo")]
        public Sexo Sexo { get; set; }

    }
}
```

ao fazer `Add-Migration` recebo a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se pode utilizar um `Enum` no caso!

Comment: assim? `public enum Sexo { M, F }` ? mas não teria que ter o `{Get; Set;}` ??

Comment: coloquei em uma resposta!

Comment: Deu certa pra você @FabioSouza ???

Comment: Então Virgílio, eu fiz, mas ainda não testei a funcionalidade, assim que testar e der certo, eu marco como aceito. Obrigado por enquanto

Comment: Retire o StringLenght esse e o problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode utilizar um `enum` com valores definidos, no caso `M = 1` e `F = 2`:

```
public enum Sexo
{
    Masculino = 1,
    Feminimo = 2
}
```

---

```
[DisplayName("SEXO")]
public Sexo Sexo { get; set; }
```

<sup>**Observação:** Nesse [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687065/How-to-Use-enum-with-Entity-Framework) tem a explicação passo a passo. O campo que é gravado na base de dados é um inteiro valores respectivos de *Masculino* e *Feminimo* do `enum` `Sexo`.</sup>

<sub>**Referencias:**</sub>

- [How to Use enum with Entity Framework 5 ?](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687065/How-to-Use-enum-with-Entity-Framework)
- [Entity Framework 6 Code First - Required Enum data type not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350377/entity-framework-6-code-first-required-enum-data-type-not-working)

Comment: ao dar Add-Migration recebo esta mensagem: `The property 'Sexo' is not a String or Byte array. Length can only be configured for String and Byte array properties.`, vou acrescentar na pergunta o que fiz

Comment: @FabioSouza retire StringLenght não tem necessidade. Lembra que ele grava inteiro !!!

Comment: Realmente tirando isso não apareceu a mensagem, mas apareceu uma nova mensagem: `Data truncated for column 'Sexo' at row 1`, O `public enum Sexo { M = 1, F = 2 }` tem que estar em classes separadas? ai eu coloquei na mesma classe `Pessoa`

Comment: @FabioSouza se antes tinha dados das essa mensagens, tem dados na tabela???

Comment: Não entendi o que quis dizer

Comment: Tem dados nessa tabela? @FabioSouza?????????????

Comment: Realmente tinha dados na tabela, mas como estava null pensei que não faria diferença, mas agora deu tudo certo. Obrigado